# Getting Object is possibly 'null'. in Angular form validators

Tags: angular, formularios, validación

Estoy intentando validar un formulario reactivo en angular y me sale este mensaje "Object is possibly 'null'" en la siguiente linea:

```
    <span *ngIf="(name.touched || name.dirty) && name.invalid && name.errors.required">
        Name is required.
    </span>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, traduce tu pregunta, el idioma oficial del sitio es el "español", saludos.

Comment: @Lorena acabo de hacer traducción de tu pregunta para que la aceptes :D

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que la propiedad error sea la que este dando el error dado que no siempre va existir (por obvias razones, no siempre va haber un error) para solucionar este el problema puede hacer uso del operador `?` evita seguir evaluando una expresión en el momento que se indefine. Puedes leer mas sobre ella acá
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Puedes solucionar agregando el operador donde obtengas ese error por ejemplo:
`name?.errors?.required`